# Ruby gsub to remove illegal characters in phone number

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I want to remove all characters in a string that do not belong in a phone number string. The first character may or may not be a "+" and all other characters must be digits.

I had `gsub(/\D/, '')`, but I want to keep the first character if it is a "+" (or a digit, of course). I then tried some negation, but this is not right, either: `gsub(/^(\+?(\d))/, '')`.

How can I ignore the first character with regex iff it is a "+"?

Comment: What about legitimate phone numbers like "1-912-555-1212x2300" or "1-888-YOU-KNOW"?

Comment: @tadman Maybe I should change the title, but the behavior I describe is the  behavior I want. :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland "The first character may or may not be a "+" and all other characters must be digits." Which part is not clear?

Comment: I beg your pardon. I missed the mention that all other characters are digits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using a negative lookahead at the beginning:

```
gsub(/(?!^\+)\D*/, '')
```

Basically, the above regex should remove any series of non-digits where the first character is not a single '+' character at the beginning of the string.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice one, Lautaro!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you absolutely have to do it in one `gsub`, it might be simpler to pull the plus sign out separately. You could use the [`[]` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D), with something like:

`my_string[/^\+/].to_s + my_string.gsub(/\D/, '')`

The `to_s` is necessary since the method will return `nil` if the plus sign isn't found.